# Jquery File Upload submit only file instead of whole form data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-file-upload

I am using jQuery file upload plug-in (basic version) https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload to upload the file in background with `carrierwave` and `rails3`.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      //auto upload files on change event
      $(function (){
        $("form input[type='file']").fileupload({
            dataType: 'script',
            add: function (e, data) {
              data.submit();
            },
            done: function (e, data){
            },
          });        
       });
    </script>
```

But `data.submit()` method submit the whole form data along with file that needs to be uploaded, which is a big problem for my application as performance is considered.

Please help me if somebody has faced this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot upload file without submitting form in rails , so if possible make another form with only file field upload button .